# How to deserialize bytes string back to numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, deserialization

Given a text array, obtained as below:

```
import numpy as np

data = [['d1', 'd2'], ['d3', 'd4'], ['d5', 'd6']]
data = np.array(data, dtype='O')
serialized = data.tobytes()
```

I need to convert it back from bytes. Here's what doesn't work:

```
>>> np.frombuffer(serialized, dtype=data.dtype)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: cannot create an OBJECT array from memory buffer
```

Comment: Object is ambiguous, it could be anything. This should work well with strings of you remove the `object` type

Comment: I have a pandas column of variable length text that for some reason doesn't convert to `U` using `df['col'] = df['col'].astype('U')`, it stays the same as `O`, that's why in this simplified example I'm using `O`

Comment: Do you have NaNs or non strings in the column? Can you try `df['col'].convert_dtypes()`?

Comment: `np.frombuffer(serialized, dtype=df['col'].dtype)
...
TypeError: Cannot interpret 'string[python]' as a data type`

Comment: Why are you using numpy for that? The data can serialized using just "pickle".

Answer (score 0):

numpy tobytes() creates a raw copy of your array. When dtype='O' your array does not contain values, but references to objects outside the array. On the other hand if you choose the string type (U as unicode) :

```py
data = [['d1', 'd2'], ['d3', 'd4'], ['d5', 'd6']]
data = np.array(data, dtype='U')
serialized = data.tobytes()
```

the result is different:

```
np.frombuffer(serialized, dtype=data.dtype)
Out[7]: array(['d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4', 'd5', 'd6'], dtype='<U2')
```

And if additionally you reshape your array:

```
In [9]: np.frombuffer(serialized, dtype=data.dtype).reshape(data.shape)
Out[9]: 
array([['d1', 'd2'],
       ['d3', 'd4'],
       ['d5', 'd6']], dtype='<U2')
```

Comment: I'm using `O` in the example because the actual example is a pandas column of text having `O` dtype. I'm currently trying to figure out why it refuses to be converted to `U` dtype.

Comment: `pandas` uses `object` dtype, and python strings, not the `numpy` `Un` string dtype.